# Behaviour of Hessian under coordinate change

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

According to this one source http://www.math.ethz.ch/~pinkri/Theses/2008-Bachelor-Andreas-Steiger.pdf, the Hessian of a function $F: \Bbb K^n \rightarrow \Bbb K$ should change under a coordinate change $F^T(X) = F(XT^{-1})$ in the following way:

$$H_{F^T}(X) = (\det T)^2 \cdot H_F(XT^{-1})$$

But I got a different answer:

$$\begin{aligned} H_{F^T}(X) &= \det J(\nabla (F(XT^{-1})))=\det J(\nabla F(XT^{-1})\cdot J (XT^{-1})) \\
& =\det J(\nabla F(XT^{-1})\cdot T^{-1}) \\
& =\det [J(\nabla F(XT^{-1}))\cdot T^{-1}] \\
& =H_F(XT^{-1})\cdot \det T^{-1} \end{aligned}$$

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't see the second line, why is $J(XT^{-1})=T^{-1}$? I assume $X$ means a vector in $\mathbb K^n$?

Comment: @GPerez $X$ is a row vector. It's probably easier to compute an example for $n=3$ to convince oneself than to read the following arguement, but here it goes. Let $T^{-1} = \{a_{ij}\}$. The $j$-th row of $J(XT^{-1})$ consists of the partial derivatives $\frac d {dX_i}$ of the $j$-th component of the vector $XT^{-1}$, which is $\sum_i a_{ji} X_i$. Hence the $ij$-th entry of $J(XT^{-1})$ is exactly $a_{ij}$.